# I have a list of dictionaries and I want to fetch the same element existed in every dictionary in Python

Tags: python

How to get the element named 'abc' from a list of dicts (which contain a key named 'abc' as well) in Python?

```
>>>y = [{123:'asd', 'xyz':'asff', 'zara':'afasf', 'abc':'afsff'},
     {123:'gfg', 'xyz':'sgggh', 'zara':'sghh', 'abc':'sfgbg'}];

>>>a=y[0]

>>>a

{123: 'asd', 'abc': 'afsff', 'xyz': 'asff', 'zara': 'afasf'}

>>>a['abc']
'afsff'

>>>b=y[0:2]

>>>b

[{123: 'asd', 'abc': 'afsff', 'xyz': 'asff', 'zara': 'afasf'},
{123:'gfg', 'xyz':'sgggh', 'zara':'sghh', 'abc':'sfgbg'}]

>>>b['abc']
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-443ce66e30fa> in <module>()
----> 1 b['abc']
```

While trying
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

I need an output like to *afasf sfgbg*

Comment: b is list, not dictionary in your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `b` variable is a list in this case, you would need to access each of its elements separately to look up the values in the dictionaries:

```
>>>b[0]['abc']
'afsff'
>>>b[1]['abc']
'sfgbg'
```

To get all the values from each dictionary in one go, you can use a for loop:

```
>>>for nested_dict in b:
...    nested_dict['abc']
'afsff'
'sfgbg'
```

The shorthand for this operation would be a list comphrehension, like this:

```
>>>[nested_dict['abc'] for nested_dict in b]
['afsff', 'sfgbg']
```

Unless all you want is to print the values, this will probably be easier to use, as it evaluates to a list by itself, which will be ready to operate on.

Comment: for y in b:
           print y['abc'] i am able to get the answer as i want but when i am using return statement in a function i am not abe to get that.Help me at that point please.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `'abc'` element of each dictionary:

```
from operator import itemgetter

y = [{123:'asd', 'xyz':'asff', 'zara':'afasf', 'abc':'afsff'},
     {123:'gfg', 'xyz':'sgggh', 'zara':'sghh', 'abc':'sfgbg'}]

print( map(itemgetter('abc'), y) )  # --> ['afsff', 'sfgbg']
```

Comment: Thank you ! but what i need is with return staement in a function

Comment: You could do something like `return map(itemgetter('abc'), y)`,

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @martineau is widely correct.

The only exception I should raise here is linked to the exception raised from the Python interpreter if the key ('abc' in this case, or **something** else in any other undefined case) could not exist in every dict of the list.

Just to simplify the extraction of the values you need, I could suggest something like this

```
`
from operator import itemgetter

list_of_dicts = [{123:'asd', 'xyz':'asff', 'zara':'afasf', 'abc':'afsff'},
     {123:'gfg', 'xyz':'sgggh', 'zara':'sghh', 'abc':'sfgbg'}];
current_key = 'abc'

try:
    print [itemgetter(current_key)(d) for d in list_of_dicts]
except:
    print 'The key %s does not exist inside %s'%(current_key, list_of_dicts)
`
```

Try to read the Python documentation of **[itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)**